# MS Access Transactions Not Working With MySQL

Tags: mysql, transactions, ms-access-2007

I'm have a problem with Transactions, in MS Access 2007 using an ODBC source to a MySQL 5.6 database. Essentially, I'm inserting a 'master' record, and then inserting 'child' records in another table. However, the records are committed even when I explicitly roll them back.

A simplified version of the function is as follows:

```
Dim ws As Workspace: Set ws = DBEngine.Workspaces(0)
Dim db As Database: Set db = CurrentDb
Dim NewID&

    ws.BeginTrans
        ' insert the "master" record
        s = "INSERT INTO ..." 
        db.Execute s

        ' get the new record ID using a passthrough query to MySQL
        NewID = gfMySQL_GetNewID  

        ' insert multiple "child" records, using the NewID 
        s = "INSERT INTO ..." 
        db.Execute s

    If vbYes = MsgBox("Commit?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo) Then
        ws.CommitTrans
    Else
        ws.Rollback
        GoTo exit_handler
    End If
```

This has me stumped, if anyone has a suggestion I would most appreciate it!

Comment: Are you using the InnoDB engine for your tables? If you're using MyISAM transactions aren't supported.

Comment: Yes Mike, using InnoDB

Comment: For diagnostic purposes, disable the code that retrieves the new ID and inserts the child records. Just `.BeginTrans`, insert one parent record, and then `.Rollback`. If that works properly then something in the code you've temporarily disabled is causing an implicit commit. (I just tested that scenario and the transaction was properly rolled back for me.)

Comment: Hi Gord, you're right. The passthrough query used in my function ( "select last_insert_id() as NewID" ) must be triggering the commit. I'll try opening a recordset and using .AddNew etc instead, so I can get the `NewID`. Thank you!

Comment: Hmmm, still stuck. For an Access table, I can open a recordset based on the table, use .AddNew, and then .Bookmark = .LastModified, so I can get the new ID. However this doesn't work for MySQL, as I get error 3167: Record is deleted. Which I guess is why long ago I resorted to using the passthrough query, and the MySQL function last_insert_id(). Any thoughts on how I can add parent and child records, within a transaction, against MySQL?

Comment: Simply using a pass-through query does not appear to be the cause of the implicit commit. I just tried it (using the same pass-through query that you used) and the subsequent `.Rollback` worked properly for me. Perhaps there is something else in your code that is causing the implicit commit?

Comment: Hi Gord, I created a new test function, gradually adding code to it, and as you said, the pass-through query did NOT force a commit, as the rollback worked AOK throughout testing. Then I retried the original function - and it worked correctly! I'm at a loss to explain what happened before. Anyway, all good now - thanks again for your help!